# Find out minimum matching pairs

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy, cumulative-sum

I have 2 list having same object with 3 properties(accNo, accType & balance).

```
List<> CSList
'CS1', 'CS', 3000
'CS2', 'CS', 2000   
'CS3', 'CS', 1000   

List<> CLList
'CL1', 'CL', 4000   
'CL2', 'CL', 500    
'CL3', 'CL', 1000
```

In my sample sum of balance of all `acctype = CS(3000+2000+1000=6000)` will be always greater than or equal to `acctype = CL(4000+500+1000=5500)`.

I am trying to clear my `CL` balances by `CS` balances. For example account `CL1` having balance 4000 which could be cleared by `CS1 & CS3(3000+1000)` or by `CS1 & CS2(3000+1000(CS2 remaining balance 1000 can be used next))`.

I want to find out the lowest number of transaction set to make `CL` accounts balances 0 by `CS` accounts (preferred output 2).

```
Possible output 1:

Debit       Credit      Amount
CS1         CL1         3000
CS2         CL1         1000
CS2         CL2         500
CS2         CL3         500
CS3         CL3         500


Possible output 2:

Debit       Credit      Amount
CS1         CL1         3000
CS3         CL1         1000
CS2         CL2         500
CS2         CL3         1000
```

Comment: Please explain downvote..

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: This is not a problem specific to any platform. Logic in java code instead of sql would help me. I am just trying to get the logic. However I have changed my tags and question for better understanding.

Comment: I doubt this (optimal matching) can be done through SQL. Would like to see a solution if it exists though.

Comment: Would `greedy knapsack` could solve this problem? And @LukStorms no matter it is not solvable through SQL, logical solution from any platform would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Greedy approach will not yield optimum result for this problem.
A solution to find optimum number of transaction:

1. Generate power set of CL account 
   e.g.((CL1,CL2,CL3), (CL1,CL2), (CL1,CL3), (CL2,CL3), (CL1), (CL2), (CL3))
2. For each subset pick all CS account which is greater than sum of the amount of subset's CL account.
3. For each picked CS account deduct the sum of subset's CL account's amount from picked CS account
4. For remaining CL accounts repeat steps 1 to 3 till all CL account deduction completed

If you have M number of CS account and N number of CL account then complexity might be O(M<sup>N</sup>*2<sup>N<sup>2</sup></sup>)

Answer (score 1):

One way to get an optimum result is to first match the credits with an equal debit.
And then match the rest and substract where needed till totally consumed.

Depending on how the debits and credits are sorted, you get a different result.
But it seems to work nice when both are sorted on ascending values.

Below is a javascript example snippet to demonstrate that tactic:

```js
var debits  = [ [ 'CS1', 3000 ], [ 'CS2', 2000 ], [ 'CS3', 1000 ], ['CS4',800] ];
var credits = [ [ 'CL1', 4000 ], [ 'CL2', 500 ], [ 'CL3', 1000 ], ['CL4',800] ];

console.log("\n# Debits and Credits sorted by ascending value\n\n");
sort_arrays(debits, 1, 1); //sort debits by ascending value
sort_arrays(credits, 1, 1); //sort credits by ascending value
console.log("Debits : "+JSON.stringify(debits));
console.log("Credits: "+JSON.stringify(credits));
var result = match_debits_to_credits (debits, credits);
sort_arrays(result, 1, 1);
console.log("Result : "+JSON.stringify(result));

console.log("\n# Debits and Credits sorted by descending value\n\n");
sort_arrays(debits, 1, -1); //sort debits by descending value
sort_arrays(credits, 1, -1); //sort credits by descending value
console.log("Debits : "+JSON.stringify(debits));
console.log("Credits: "+JSON.stringify(credits));
var result = match_debits_to_credits (debits, credits);
sort_arrays(result, 1, 1);
console.log("Result : "+JSON.stringify(result));

console.log("\n# Credits and Debits sorted by ascending name.\n# And without matching the same values first.\n\n");
sort_arrays(debits, 0, 1); //sort debits by ascending name
sort_arrays(credits, 0, 1); //sort credits by ascending name
console.log("Debits : "+JSON.stringify(debits));
console.log("Credits: "+JSON.stringify(credits));
var result = match_debits_to_credits (debits, credits, false);
sort_arrays(result, 1, 1);
console.log("Result : "+JSON.stringify(result));

function sort_arrays (p_array, index = 0, order_direction = 1){
  p_array.sort(
    function(a, b){
      return a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : a[index]<b[index] ? -order_direction : order_direction
    });
}

function match_debits_to_credits (p_debits, p_credits, p_match_equal_first = true){

  let output = [];
  let v_debits = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p_debits));
  let v_credits = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p_credits));
  
  if(p_match_equal_first){
    // First match the credit with an equal debit
    for (let i=0; i < v_credits.length; i++){
  
      for (let j=0; j < v_debits.length; j++){
  
        if (v_credits[i][1] == v_debits[j][1]){
  
          console.log('credit ' + v_credits[i] + ' = debit ' + v_debits[j]);
          output.push([ v_debits[j][0], v_credits[i][0], v_credits[i][1] ]);
  
          v_credits.splice(i,1); i--; //consumed by the matching debit
          v_debits.splice(j,1); //consumed by the matching credit
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  for (let i=0; i < v_credits.length; i++){

    for (let j=0; j < v_debits.length && v_credits[i][1] > 0; j++){

      if (v_debits[j][1] > 0 && v_credits[i][1] > v_debits[j][1]){

        console.log('credit ' + v_credits[i] + ' > debit ' + v_debits[j]);
        v_credits[i][1] = v_credits[i][1] - v_debits[j][1];

        output.push([ v_debits[j][0], v_credits[i][0], v_debits[j][1] ]);

        v_debits.splice(j,1); j--; //consumed by the credit
      }
      else if (v_credits[i][1] <= v_debits[j][1]){

        console.log('credit ' + v_credits[i] + ' <= debit ' + v_debits[j]);
        v_debits[j][1] = v_debits[j][1] - v_credits[i][1];

        output.push([ v_debits[j][0], v_credits[i][0], v_credits[i][1] ]);

        if(v_debits[j][1] == 0) {v_debits.splice(j,1);}
        v_credits.splice(i,1); i--; //consumed by the debit
        break; //no need for further matching for this credit
      }
    }
  }
  
  return output;
  
}
```

Not sure how to calculate the complexity for this though.
Because of the breaks that exit a loop when a credit is totally consumed.
If M is the number of credits and N is the number of Debits.
Then I assume the complexity could be something like `O(M*N+M*2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd give a try doing this in SQL.
The same tactic is used as in my other answer.

The [T-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) below is for SQL server.

```
declare @Transactions table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(30), type char(2), value int, accountid int);
insert into @Transactions (name, type, value, accountid) values
('CS1','CS',3000,1),('CS2','CS',2000,1),('CS3','CS',1000,1),
('CL1','CL',4000,1),('CL2','CL', 500,1),('CL3','CL',1000,1);

declare @Credits table (creditid int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(30), value int);
declare @Debits table (debitid int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(30), value int);
declare @Result table (resultid int identity(1,1) primary key, accountid int, 
                       credit_name varchar(30), credit_value int, debit_name varchar(30), debit_value int, debited int, credit_remaining int, 
                       loopcnt int, comparison varchar(2));

declare @AccountId int;
set @AccountId = 1;

insert into @Credits (name, value) 
select name, value
from @Transactions
where type = 'CL' and accountid = @AccountId
order by value asc, id;

insert into @Debits (name, value) 
select name, value
from @Transactions
where type = 'CS' and accountid = @AccountId
order by value asc, id;

declare @TotalCredits INT;
declare @TotalDebits INT;
declare @CounterCredits INT;
declare @CounterDebits INT;

declare @CurrentCreditName varchar(30);
declare @CurrentCreditValue int;
declare @RemainingCreditValue int;
declare @Debited int;
declare @LoopCnt int = 0;

declare @CurrentDebitName varchar(30);
declare @CurrentDebitValue int;

set @TotalCredits = (select count(*) from @Credits);
set @TotalDebits = (select count(*) from @Debits);

set @CounterCredits = 1;
WHILE @CounterCredits <= @TotalCredits
BEGIN
   select @CurrentCreditName = name, @CurrentCreditValue = value, @RemainingCreditValue = value
   from @Credits where creditid = @CounterCredits;

   set @CounterDebits = 1;
   WHILE @RemainingCreditValue > 0 AND @CounterDebits <= @TotalDebits
   BEGIN
       set @LoopCnt = @LoopCnt + 1;

       select @CurrentDebitName = name, @CurrentDebitValue = value 
       from @Debits where debitid = @CounterDebits;

       if(@RemainingCreditValue = @CurrentDebitValue)
       begin
           set @Debited = @CurrentDebitValue;
           set @RemainingCreditValue = 0;

           update @Credits set value = 0 where creditid = @CounterCredits;
           update @Debits  set value = 0 where debitid = @CounterDebits;

           insert into @Result (accountid, credit_name, credit_value, debit_name, debit_value, debited, credit_remaining, loopcnt, comparison) 
           values (@AccountId, @CurrentCreditName, @CurrentCreditValue, @CurrentDebitName, @CurrentDebitValue, @Debited, @RemainingCreditValue, @LoopCnt, '=');
       end;

       set @CounterDebits = @CounterDebits + 1;
   END;
   set @CounterCredits = @CounterCredits + 1;
END;

set @CounterCredits = 1;
WHILE @CounterCredits <= @TotalCredits
BEGIN
   select @CurrentCreditName = name, @CurrentCreditValue = value, @RemainingCreditValue = value 
   from @Credits where creditid = @CounterCredits;

   set @CounterDebits = 1;
   set @TotalDebits = (select count(*) from @Debits);

   WHILE @CounterDebits <= @TotalDebits AND @RemainingCreditValue > 0
   BEGIN
       set @LoopCnt = @LoopCnt + 1;

       select @CurrentDebitName = name, @CurrentDebitValue = value 
       from @Debits where debitid = @CounterDebits;

       IF(@CurrentDebitValue > 0 AND @RemainingCreditValue >= @CurrentDebitValue)
       BEGIN
           set @Debited = @CurrentDebitValue;
           set @RemainingCreditValue = @RemainingCreditValue - @CurrentDebitValue;

           update @Credits set value = @RemainingCreditValue where creditid = @CounterCredits;
           update @Debits set value = 0 where debitid = @CounterDebits;

           insert into @Result (accountid, credit_name, credit_value, debit_name, debit_value, debited, credit_remaining, loopcnt, comparison) 
           values (@AccountId, @CurrentCreditName, @CurrentCreditValue, @CurrentDebitName, @CurrentDebitValue, @Debited, @RemainingCreditValue, @LoopCnt, '>=');

           set @CurrentCreditValue = @RemainingCreditValue;
       END;
       ELSE IF(@RemainingCreditValue > 0 AND @RemainingCreditValue < @CurrentDebitValue)
       BEGIN
           set @Debited = @RemainingCreditValue;
           set @RemainingCreditValue = 0;

           update @Credits set value = 0 where creditid = @CounterCredits;
           update @Debits set value = value - @Debited where debitid = @CounterDebits;

           insert into @Result (accountid, credit_name, credit_value, debit_name, debit_value, debited, credit_remaining, loopcnt, comparison) 
           values (@AccountId, @CurrentCreditName, @CurrentCreditValue, @CurrentDebitName, @CurrentDebitValue, @Debited, @RemainingCreditValue, @LoopCnt, '<');

       END;

       set @CounterDebits = @CounterDebits + 1;
   END;

   set @CounterCredits = @CounterCredits + 1;
END;

select 
debit_name as Debit, 
credit_name as Credit,
debited as Amount
from @Result
order by debit_name, credit_name;
```

**Result:**

```
Debit Credit Amount
----- ------ ------
CS1   CL1    2500
CS2   CL1    1500
CS2   CL2    500
CS3   CL3    1000
```