# Distribute negative account balances to positive account balances to minimize the amount left over

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, logic

Using excel, I have a list of accounts in column A (call them Account 1, Account 2, Account 3, etc.). In column B, I have an account balance for each individual account, ranging from -10.00 to 10.00.

For clarity:

```
Col A        Col B
Account 1    -5.15
Account 2     3.94
Account 3     9.13
Account 4    -0.33
Account 5     8.04
etc.
```

I'm dealing with hundreds of accounts.

What I would like to do, is figure out the most efficient way to balance every account to zero. And do so by allocating negative balances to positive balances. Whether that be multiple accounts with negative balances being consolidated to balance 1 account with a positive balance, or 1 negative account balancing multiple positive accounts. My goal is to have the value left over after every account has been balanced to zero, to be as close to zero as possible.

Lastly, in col C, I'd like the cells in each row to call out which account(s) to pull from, to balance the account in col A to zero. In col D, I'd like the cells in each row to call out the value needed from the account(s) in col C, to be allocated to the account in col A.

I'm not sure if this can be done with formulas, or using VBA. Each and every solution is more than welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a free code writing service, but we'll be happy to help you fix a problem you have with your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. I am not sure where to even start. I've done plenty of research hoping to find similar questions. However, I cannot seem to find anything. I'm not familiar enough with logic required to accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: Sounds like formulas may do (most of) everything you need. Create a small sample of 10-20 rows of data (accounts and balances) in Columns A and B. Then specifically write down exactly how you would calculate the balance of each and the logic of driving that balance to zero. This paper exercise will really clarify in your own mind the exact steps you need to take. You have the idea, but you need to create the exact steps. Once you have that, try some of the formulas and/or come back and ask a more specific question and show your sample data so we can help.

Comment: Add up all of the accounts, divide by the total number of accounts, then set each account to that value as the "target" ? Subtract "excess" from the larger accounts and assign to those accounts which need funds?

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Peter, what I want to do is, 1) Find the highest positive value in the range (C3:C150). 2) Balance that to zero by allocating quantities from account(s) with negative values. 3) In adjacent columns, display which accounts to pull from, and how much to pull from them. 4) Find next highest positive value. 5) Repeat steps 2) - 3).

Comment: This question is very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish. However, I'm not sure how to apply to posted solutions to excel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394949/find-out-minimum-matching-pairs

Answer (score 0):

Not much data to test with but try this. It first sorts the data on Sheet1 by column B. The credits and matching debits appear on Sheet2. It only tries to match single values so wouldn't choose two smaller values that might be a better match than one larger value.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub AccountMatch()
    
    Dim iLastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim credit As Currency, debit As Currency

    iLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = i
    Next

    ' results sheet
    Sheet2.Cells.Clear
    iRow = 1
   
    ' sort values
    With Sheet1.Sort
         With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & iLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                 Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
         End With
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & iLastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' match credit to debits
    i = 2
    credit = Sheet1.Cells(i, "B")
    Do While credit > 0
        iRow = iRow + 1
        Sheet2.Cells(iRow, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
        Sheet2.Cells(iRow, 2) = credit

        ' match negative moving upwards
        For j = iLastRow To 1 Step -1
            If Sheet1.Cells(j, 4) = "" Then
                debit = Sheet1.Cells(j, "B")
                If debit > 0 Then Exit For
                If credit + debit > 0 Then
                    Sheet2.Cells(iRow, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 1)
                    Sheet2.Cells(iRow, 4) = debit
                    iRow = iRow + 1
                    'mark as matched
                    Sheet1.Cells(j, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
                    credit = credit + debit
                 End If
             End If
        Next
        Sheet2.Cells(iRow, 3) = "Remaining"
        Sheet2.Cells(iRow, 4) = credit

        ' next largest credit
        i = i + 1
        credit = Sheet1.Cells(i, "B")
    Loop

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```